# My phone's screen is broken; I'd like to transfer files to my PC, but can't, because Charging Mode is enabled by default

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, file-transfer, broken-screen, mtp

My phone's screen is broken and I'd like to transfer files from it to my pc, but I can't acces them as Charging Mode is enabled by default. Does anyone have any idea how I can get access to my files through my pc? My phone is a rooted Motorola Moto X Style, running Cyanogenmod 13.

Thanks alot!

Comment: OK thanks.  What's "Charging Mode"?  Also, do you plan to ever fix your phone's screen?  You can probably order all the necessary parts and tools online. I don't know whether it's a better deal for you to repair or replace the phone.

Comment: @unforgettableid Since Android 6/MM, when you connect your device via USB it defaults to "charge only" (instead of automatically enabling MTP, as it did before).

Comment: h-beneuh: How broken is your phone's screen? Can you see anything at all? Also, does the screen recognize any of your taps?

Comment: @h-beneuh Before I again forget to mention it: Please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info). Lots of useful information collected there already.

Comment: @unforgettableid, i can see everything, but the touch screen is broken too so it doesn't react on my taps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to access MTP mode via TWRP (Which i guess you have installed...) If you've installed TWRP, simply boot into recovery and connect your USB cable, you should be able to access your device via MTP then.

If you're not using TWRP, you can

- [download a TWRP image](http://twrp.me/devices/motorolamotox2013.html)
- boot your device into [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader) mode
- use `fastboot boot twrp.img` to temporarily boot into TWRP

Another alternative, again from [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode), would be using `adb pull` to retrieve the files. This is usually supported by all recoveries.

Answer (score 0):

nothing to worry about u can just download motorola device manager v.2.5.4 from motorola website.then try to transfer your data to ur pc. becuse now it will act as usb device.

if that doesnot resolve ur problem download motorola e toolkit setup .
 if further problem exist contact me

Comment: Does the device automatically switch to the correct mode just because that software is running on a computer? Speaking of which: What OS does it need, or is it cross-platform? And where to "just download" it from? Same for the "toolkit setup". Could you please [edit] your post and fill the gaps? Thanks in advance!